# Implement "Forgot password" function in Azure Mobile Service

Tags: java, azure, azure-mobile-services

Using Android and Java Script backend.

I am saving my user data to a table in Azure mobile services. I need to give "forgot password" functionality for users. Any one please suggest me a optimum solution for adding this functionality. Do I have to purchase an add-on or something?

Comment: Is there any user account information in the data table? like email address, phone number, etc?

Comment: Made some minor copy edits

Comment: @peter pan : yes. My table have email address and password.

Comment: @SHINERAJARATHIL OK, try these solutions of my post.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT Thank you sir. I am trying sendgrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, there are two ways to impliment forgot password function in Azure Mobile Service if user account information includes email account, phone number.

Solution 1: Email password reset link to User

You can use the "SendGrid" Service on Azure Marketplace to email a password reset link to user registed mailbox what selected in table by phone number or user name. User change the password thru the reset link page on PC browser.

About using "SendGrid" to send email, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-sendgrid-mobile-services-send-email-scripts/.

Solution 2: Send a confirm code thru SMS

You can use the "Twilio" Service on Azure Marketplace to send a confirm code thru SMS in Android Client. User change the password on Android form UI after confirm the received code by sending back it to Mobile Service.

About using "Twilio" to send SMS, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-twilio-mobile-services-how-to-use-voice-sms/#howto_send_sms.

Best Regards.